# How to configure Detox in expo android project to test locally, without eject if possible?

Tags: react-native, detox

I want to run Detox in one of my expo project. The documentation and method I have found are of React Native project without Expo.
Is there any way to configure detox in an Expo project.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like the relevant documentation in expo:
https://docs.expo.dev/build-reference/e2e-tests/

And the relevant example repository:
https://github.com/expo/eas-tests-example

Comment: Thanks, the trouble I am facing is to configure it for android and test it locally.